# Create a new database through neo4j client

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

How to create a new database in neo4j through neo4j .net readify client?? by default it takes me to the same database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j does not have a concept of multiple databases. Either run Neo4j on different ports with different `graph.db` directories or use multiple subgraphs in one Neo4j instance.

Comment: how to create subgraphs?are subgraphs similar to labels??

Comment: subgraphs are just parts of your graphs having not relationships in between, so you cannot navigate between them. This has nothing to do with labels. However you can use distinct labels for different parts of your graph.